# How to increase the 10-20% of load after every 20-30 min in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In my test plan I have 5 Thread groups with following number of users for 1HR,

1. Bulk Upload - 250 User
2. Log Analyzer - 50 User
3. Library - 10 User
4. CSV File Processer - 5 User
5. XLS File Processer - 5 User

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For  a particular execution I want to follow the following pattern,

**Objective :**

- Want to execute this for 2HR (this is easy which I changed in the duration)
- After every 20-30 min I want to increase the load to 10-20%
  means after 30 min (example) the total user for Bulk Upload will became 275 User (if it is 10%) and similar for others and going to execute for 30 min.
  And after 1HR of test Bulk Upload will became 302 User and similar for others and going to execute for 30 min.

Is there any way we can do this in JMeter in the same script during the execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by using a `Ultimate thread group` with the following settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to just increase the total number of threads to 40-80% and amend the ramp-up period accordingly.

Alternatively you can consider using i.e. [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) or [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) where you can flexibly specify users arrival rate, something like:

[image]

These thread groups can be installed as a part of **Custom Thread Groups** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]